# Should I use URLDownloadToFile?

Tags: c++, file, download

I am looking for the most simple way to download a file in C++ (on Windows).
URLDownloadToFile sounds great and does not require me to use curl or other fat libraries that I don't need - what are the requirements for this function? Which Windows's will it run on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28VS.85%29.aspx

The documentation is there for a reason.

E: Just glancing at the documentation, it requires a minimum of Internet Explorer 3.0 and Windows 95. Vanishingly few computers do not meet those requirements.

E: Here's a sample of how to use this function. You also need to link `Urlmon.lib` to compile:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <Urlmon.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("URLDownloadToFile test function.\n");

    TCHAR url[] = TEXT("http://google.com");

    printf("Url: %S\n", url);

    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];

    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);

    wsprintf(path, TEXT("%s\\index.html"), path);

    printf("Path: %S\n", path);

    HRESULT res = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, url, path, 0, NULL);

    if(res == S_OK) {
        printf("Ok\n");
    } else if(res == E_OUTOFMEMORY) {
        printf("Buffer length invalid, or insufficient memory\n");
    } else if(res == INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE) {
        printf("URL is invalid\n");
    } else {
        printf("Other error: %d\n", res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I completely agree, however this function is located under the .NET Framework 3.0 section in MSDN which is what puzzled me (since this function is a native win32api function). Could you please let me know the exact requirements? I appreciate your help!

Comment: It's... not, though. It's under Web Development > Internet Explorer Development > URL Monikers > URL Monikers > Reference > Functions. No .NET at all. If you want a sample, that might take me a bit, since I've never used this api before.

Comment: I've added a sample of how to use the function in question. You can get download progress if you use COM, but I'm not very familiar with that. However, as a simple downloader, you don't need anything fancy.

Answer (score 2):

I use this function in a WTL C++ app and have yet to come across any PC that didn't support it (the app in question has been installed on thousands of clients, a mix of Windows 2000, XP, Vista and Windows 7).  There are no .NET dependencies either BTW - it's buried in an old Internet Explorer Win32 DLL.  It is very simple to use, accepts any URL and even a normal DOS-style filename will work (we sometimes use it to fetch files from a network share.)

Comment: Rob, is this method reliable? Sometimes when I try to download 5MB png images, it fails for the first attempt. But strangely second attempt download the file without any issue. Any recommendation for that please?

Answer (score 1):

How exactly do you want this file downloaded, and from what source? If it is from your own source I can think of quite a few better ways, and more portable ways.

If you have the desire to download from your own source, simply set up a socket on either side, send the filesize, then send an array of chars from an fstream receive the array of characters and write to the destination fstream.

Comment: I need to download a file over HTTP. My bad for not mentioning it!

Comment: No problem mate! Hopefully I could help anyway.