# URLDownloadToFile not downloading file from browser

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

URL download to file is not downloading the zip file, the code hangs on URLDownloadToFile(..)
below is the code:

```
CString sZipFile = "d:\myFolder\abc-candidate\candidate.zip"
CString sSource = "http://test.abc.com/cs/Ds/Es/F/GHI/candidate//file1" 
    HRESULT res = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, sSource, sZipFile, 0, NULL);
    if (res == S_OK) {
        printf("Ok\n");
    }
```

Comment: URLDownloadToFile has return values other than 'S_OK'. So, what is the value returned in this case ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184988/should-i-use-urldownloadtofile/5185008] has example code in the solution by @Mike Caron ... maybe you can try it to et some hints

Comment: Even with no warnings turned on, I get warnings from MSVC about this. Start with those.

Comment: E_ABORT Operation aborted. this is the returned value

Comment: `sZipFile` is missing backslashes. Try downloading in parts https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552504/4603670

Comment: `"d:\myFolder\abc-candidate\candidate.zip"` -> `"d:\\myFolder\\abc-candidate\\candidate.zip"`. Didn't you get compiler warnings?